# Stuck at apt since it tries to set up a mysql server

Tags: apt, mysql

when I try to run `sudo apt upgrade` it says

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Then when running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` it says

```
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
mysqld is running as pid 4368
```

then the command will run and run with no response or change !

ctrl+C wont stop it from running and upgrading and installing is impossible since it will try to start with setting up the mysql server which will result in errors

Do you know how I can fix this since I cant install anything !

EDIT: now it runs 1,5h without a new response

EDIT EDIT : I checked which mysql version is currently installed and running perfectly fine

```
Server version: 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: Did you experience errors when you installed mysql? Also, what version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I didnt get any errors (as far as i can remember ). I had problems with phpmyadmin (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73126243/phpmyadmin-throws-alot-errors-linux-ubuntu) but those work now . Besides these Errors .
My Ubuntu version is `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS` @OrganicMarble

Comment: did you check /var/log/mysql/error.log ?

Comment: Yeah there are no new errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by deleting and reinstalling mysql

Comment: this isn't an acceptable solution... How about all databases on the machine??

Answer (score 0):

I solved by killing the `mysqld` process:

```
ps aux | grep -i "mysqld"

sudo kill 2370 (here 2370 is the process ID displayed by the command above)
```

After did it, the `sudo dpkg --configure -a` command will continue without restart it.